# Python pandas NameError: StringIO is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, stringio

I am unable to read data in Pandas:
Input:

```
import pandas as pd

data = 'a,b,c\n1,2,3\n4,5,6'

pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),skipinitialspace=True)
```

Output:

```
NameError:name 'StringIO' is not defined
```

Please let me know why the error occurred and also let me know what to import.

Comment: [Should we use pandas.compat.StringIO or Python 2/3 StringIO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283292/should-we-use-pandas-compat-stringio-or-python-2-3-stringio)

Answer (score 29):

Found the solution here:

The error occurred because I didn't import `StringIO`.  Unlike Python 2, in Python 3 you are required to import it.

```
from io import StringIO
```

After importing no error occurred.
Output to the above question was:

```
   a b c
0  1 2 3
1  4 5 6
```

It can also be imported from `pandas.compat`  which works for both Python 2 and 3.

```
from pandas.compat import StringIO
```

Comment: In Python 2, you are also required to import it, just from a different module (also named `StringIO`).

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the below packages 
These packages should add this line at the beginning of your script.

```
import io
from io import StringIO
import string
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
from collections import Counter

try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO
```

After adding the above packages I am not getting the below error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'StringIO'
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because it was removed in python 3 for a better module.

From [What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html):

> The `StringIO` and `cStringIO` modules are gone. Instead, import the `io` module and use `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO` for text and data respectively.

```
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO
```

Answer (score -1):

StringIO needs to be imported as `import StringIO` before it can be used

EDIT: 
link for more information: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html